# a.out path in Linux Source code

Tags: kernel

I have idea when we do `./a.out` from terminal it goes to `load_elf_binary()` function in `fs/binfmt_elf.c`. I want full path of a.out from which `structure/functions` it goes so I will understand working of `a.out` executable in detail.

Thank You !

Comment: `load_elf_library` function accepts argument of type `struct linux_binprm*`. This structure is defined in `/include/linux/binfmts.h` and contains field `file`, using which you can traverse full path to executable.

Comment: Will you please elaborate.

Comment: I want the complete path by which a.out gets execute

Answer (score 0):

Inside function

```
static int load_elf_binary(struct linux_binprm *bprm)
```

expression `bprm->file` refers to file object, corresponded to the executable file. So, you may have path to that file, e.g., using

```
dentry_path_raw(bprm->file->f_path.dentry, buf, buflen);
```

(You should declare `buf` and `buflen` before, and after that call `buf` will contain path to the file).